# JSF - List of objects in a Managed Bean and memory management question

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am creating my first JSF application. For this question I am going to simplify everything to try and make my question as clear as possible.

The application I am creating is a simple contact storing application that will allow you to create a new contact, store information such as addresses, phone numbers, where they work, and upload files that are associated to the contact.

When the application loads the user is displayed with a list of contacts that have already been created. They can click on the contact's image to open up the contact and view all of the information stored on them. This is where my question comes in.

All of this information is stored in the **ContactManager.java** managed bean. All of the data on the contact is displayed in datatables. So there is an address datatable, phone datatable, uploads datatable. Each datatable view resides within an appropriate tab. I am using Primefaces to create the tabs. So basically when a contact is opened the system has to load maybe about 10 lists of data as well as dropwdown lists used for select values. to populate these datatables in the tabs.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ContactManager implements Serializable {

     private Contact contactInfo;
     private List<Phone> phones;
     private List<Addresses> addresses;
     private List<Company> jobs;
     private List<Files> uploads;

     //dropdown select lists
     private List<Country> countryList;
     private List<State> stateList;

     //Getters and setters for everyting
     ..... (I am not going to type it all out but its there)


     @PostConstruct 
     public void openContact() {
         try {
             this.countryList = myDao.getCountryList();
             this.stateList = myDao.getStateList();
             this.addresses = myDao.getAddresses(contactInfo.contactId);
             this.phones = myDao.getPhones(contactInfo.contactId);
             this.jobs = myDao.getJobs(contactInfo.contactId);
             this.uploads = myDao.getUploads(contactInfo.contactId);
         }
     }  
}
```

So basically when a user opens a contact all of that contact information is loaded into memory so it can be displayed in the view.

This example is small to the actual amount of lists and data that I am storing but for simplification sake I am wondering about memory management.

My system is going to be used by a number of users and loading all of this information worries me. When does the memory allocated for all of this get cleared? Am I responsible for clearing it?

If I have 10 users and they are all viewing contacts that have really big tables with a lot of data I fear that this is going to bring everything to a standstill.

Currently it runs fine on my system but I know that all of these tables and lists are kept in memory until either the user clicks and opens a new contact or closes the application.

Any insight on if this is the right way of doing things or how to handle large information like this would be great.

I am using JSF 2.0 / Primefaces 2.2RC2-Snapshot

Comment: Have you thought about using `@RequestScope` to free that memory as soon as possible ( after request is served ) or about using Ajax calls with `@ViewScope` and only particular loading in the `@PostConstruct` method and rest of data load on demand ( tab switching )?

Comment: @Gaim I have thought about loading it on demand during tab switching but what if the user clicks through all of the tabs. Then all of the data has been loaded into the member variables. It is an improvement up until the point when the users views all the data. Do I need to handle when they click away from a tab and set the current tab's object data to null or something?

Comment: @Gaim - Also @RequestScope does not work for my application because there is some information that I have to keep persistant such as the contactId and some view specific variable used for navigation.

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are big, you need a lot of memory on server side, with or without JSF.

Do not use rich faces tables; use ui:repeat and write custom paging for it.

primefaces tables are better than h:dataTable or rich:datatable.

JSF 2.0 uses 50% less memory for each user.

Also, use @RequestScoped beans and ViewScoped; do not use SessionScoped beans.

You also can remove sessions beans from session from faces context.

```
context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
externalContext = context.getExternalContext();  
externalContext.getSessionMap().remove("UserContext");
externalContext.getSessionMap().remove("SessionController");
```

Etc.

Also, if you have some id for store in the page and you think you can not use RequestScoped beans, it is mistake
integrate with your application tomahawk myfaces, and use t:saveState value="#{bean.categoryId}"/>

it is store id or objects, list maps, in the current page scope.