# How to reference a List<> of objects, in a managed bean, from a JSF xhtml page?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

maybe I do not know how to ask my question, and that is why I cannot find an answer.  So, here we go.

I am just playing around/testing some stuff and I am stumped when using a List<> in a non-managed bean (or managed for that matter).

I have a java managed bean called PayrollSummaryWizard.java, for use with the primeFaces wizard. Inside this managed bean, I have a java class, which contains 2 lists.  One holds one type of commission, and the other list holds another. I set these commissions up as their own java classes.

```
package com.testing.xx.payrollsummary;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import org.primefaces.event.FlowEvent;

@ViewScoped
@Named
public class PayrollSummaryWizard implements Serializable {

    private PayrollSummary payrollSummary = new PayrollSummary();

    public PayrollSummary getPayrollSummary() {
        return payrollSummary;
    }

    public void setPayrollSummary(PayrollSummary payrollSummary) {
        this.payrollSummary = payrollSummary;
    }

    private String onFlowProcess(FlowEvent event)
    {
        return event.getNewStep();
    }

    private void save()
    {

    }
}


package com.testing.xx.payrollsummary;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class PayrollSummary implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private List<CountCommission> countCommissions;

    public List<CountCommission> getCountCommissions() {
        return carCommissions;
    }

    public void setCountCommissions(List<CountCommission> countCommissions) {
        this.countCommissions = countCommissions;
    }

    public List<SalesCommission> getSalesCommissions() {
        return salesCommissions;
    }

    public void setSalesCommissions(List<SalesCommission> salesCommissions) {
        this.salesCommissions = salesCommissions;
    }

    public Long getManagersEmployeeNumber() {
        return managersEmployeeNumber;
    }

    public void setManagersEmployeeNumber(Long managersEmployeeNumber) {
        this.managersEmployeeNumber = managersEmployeeNumber;
    }

    public String getStore() {
        return store;
    }

    public void setStore(String store) {
        this.store = store;
    }
    private List<SalesCommission> salesCommissions;
    private Long managersEmployeeNumber;
    private String store;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof PayrollSummary)) {
            return false;
        }
        PayrollSummary other = (PayrollSummary) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}

package com.testing.xx.payrollsummary;

        import java.io.Serializable;
        import javax.persistence.Entity;
        import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
        import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
        import javax.persistence.Id;


        @Entity
        public class SalesCommission implements Serializable {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
            private Long id;
            private Double salesAmount;

            public Double getSalesAmount() {
                return salesAmount;
            }

            public void setSalesAmount(Double salesAmount) {
                this.salesAmount = salesAmount;
            }

            public Long getEmployeeNumber() {
                return employeeNumber;
            }

            public void setEmployeeNumber(Long employeeNumber) {
                this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
            }
            private Long employeeNumber;

            public Long getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public void setId(Long id) {
                this.id = id;
            }
    @Override
                public int hashCode() {
                    int hash = 0;
                    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
                    return hash;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean equals(Object object) {
                    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
                    if (!(object instanceof SalesCommission)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    SalesCommission other = (SalesCommission) object;
                    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }

            }
```

The problem comes in, inside the xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:panelGrid>
                <p:wizard flowListener="#{payrollSummaryWizard.onFlowProcess}">
                    <p:tab id="personal" title="Personal">
                        <p:panel header="Personal Details">
                            <p:messages />
                            <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">
                                <h:outputLabel for="managersEmployeeNumber" value="Manager's Employee Number:" />
                                <p:inputText id="managersEmployeeNumber" value="#{payrollSummaryWizard.payrollSummary.managersEmployeeNumber}" required="true" label="Manager's Employee Number"/>

                                <h:outputLabel for="store" value="Store:" />
                                <p:inputText id="store" value="#{payrollSummaryWizard.payrollSummary.store}" required="true" label="Store"/>
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </p:panel>
                    </p:tab>
                    <p:tab id="personal" title="Personal">
                        <p:panel header="Personal Details">
                            <p:messages />
                            <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">
                                <h:outputLabel for="salesCommission_employeeNumber" value="Employee Number:" />
                                <p:inputText id="salesCommission_employeeNumber" value="#{payrollSummaryWizard.payrollSummary.salesCommissions.??}" required="true" label="Employee Number"/>


                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </p:panel>
                    </p:tab>
                </p:wizard>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

How do I access that list?

```
value="#{payrollSummaryWizard.payrollSummary.salesCommissions.??}"
```

where ??, I am trying to do the employee number.  Was trying with an array type, but it doesnt look like that would work?

EDIT: I am not sure if it matters, but the reason I was thinking like this is because, it would be nice to have an "Add" button on the page, where dynamic new fields would show up and they can be mapped back to the list, if that makes sense. This way, I could add more employee sales commissions on 1 form for the week.

I found two similar questions on here, but they weren't quite this. Here is one because I lost the link to the other one :/

[JSF - List of objects in a Managed Bean and memory management question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922232/jsf-list-of-objects-in-a-managed-bean-and-memory-management-question)

EDIT: I do not think this should be considered a duplicate question because, the other questions that are similar provide an answer that does not work for this.  All you get are null references.  I have tried using the [0].employeeNumber because, my thinking is that the list can be accessed like an array, only, here, even with an @PostConstruct to initialize, or without, it still throws a null pointer reference.  Second, the actual list is not stored within the @ManagedBean, it's in a POJO being referenced by a managed bean.

Sorry I am so scatterbrained, like I said, I am not sure how to ask this question.

So, here is the code that I have tried currently:

```
package com.testing.xx.payrollsummary;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import org.primefaces.event.FlowEvent;

/**
 *
 * @author cfranklin
 */
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean
public class PayrollSummaryWizard implements Serializable {
    private PayrollSummary payrollSummary = new PayrollSummary();
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        payrollSummary = new PayrollSummary();
    }
    public PayrollSummary getPayrollSummary() {
        return payrollSummary;
    }

    public void setPayrollSummary(PayrollSummary payrollSummary) {
        this.payrollSummary = payrollSummary;
    }

    public String onFlowProcess(FlowEvent event) {
        return event.getNewStep();
    }

    private void save() {

    }
}
```

In this @ManagedBean, I have tried all of the different scopes, none work.  Second, in the past, when I wanted to fill an array with the @PostConstruct to pass to a dropdwon, for some reason, the scope mattered, which is why I tried all of them now.

the POJO that the @ManagedBean is referencing is like so:

```
package com.testing.xx.payrollsummary;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class PayrollSummary implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany
    private List<CountCommission> countCommissions = new ArrayList();
    @OneToMany
    private List<SalesCommission> salesCommissions = new ArrayList();
    private Long managersEmployeeNumber;
    private String store;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void PayrollSummary(){
         salesCommissions = new ArrayList();
         carCommissions = new ArrayList();
    }

    public List<CountCommission> getCountCommissions() {
        return countCommissions;
    }

    public void setCountCommissions(List<CountCommission> countCommissions) {
        this.countCommissions = countCommissions;
    }

    public List<SalesCommission> getSalesCommissions() {
        return salesCommissions;
    }

    public void setSalesCommissions(List<SalesCommission> salesCommissions) {
        this.salesCommissions = salesCommissions;
    }

    public Long getManagersEmployeeNumber() {
        return managersEmployeeNumber;
    }

    public void setManagersEmployeeNumber(Long managersEmployeeNumber) {
        this.managersEmployeeNumber = managersEmployeeNumber;
    }

    public String getStore() {
        return store;
    }

    public void setStore(String store) {
        this.store = store;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof PayrollSummary)) {
            return false;
        }
        PayrollSummary other = (PayrollSummary) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is one of the objects that belongs in the list

```
package com.testing.xx.payrollsummary;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class SalesCommission implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Long employeeNumber;
    private Double salesAmount;

    @OneToOne
    private PayrollSummary payrollSummary;

    public PayrollSummary getPayrollSummary() {
        return payrollSummary;
    }

    public void setPayrollSummary(PayrollSummary payrollSummary) {
        this.payrollSummary = payrollSummary;
    }

    public Double getSalesAmount() {
        return salesAmount;
    }

    public void setSalesAmount(Double salesAmount) {
        this.salesAmount = salesAmount;
    }

    public Long getEmployeeNumber() {
        return employeeNumber;
    }

    public void setEmployeeNumber(Long employeeNumber) {
        this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof SalesCommission)) {
            return false;
        }
        SalesCommission other = (SalesCommission) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am just keeping this part short and simple for readability:

```
<p:inputText id="saleCommission_employeeNumber_0" value="#{payrollSummaryWizard.payrollSummary.saleCommissions[0].employeeNumber}" required="true" label="Employee Number"/>
```

outputs

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @30,203 value="#{payrollSummaryWizard.payrollSummary.saleCommissions[0].employeeNumber}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null
```

Hence, I do not think [Get specific element in a list or array using EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637285/get-specific-element-in-a-list-or-array-using-el) applies in this situation.  Or maybe it does and I am not initializing properly? I've also tried doing that a few different ways.

Comment: e.g. for the list item at position `index` you are able to access it like that: `"#{payrollSummaryWizard.payrollSummary.salesCommissions[index]}"` ...but I am quite unsure what your final intent exactly looks like

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637285/get-specific-element-in-a-list-or-array-using-el

Comment: Well, thanks. I will try it out again. I did that before, but it wasn't working.

Comment: Okay, so I followed the other post and I get errors lol javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @30,203 value="#{payrollSummaryWizard.payrollSummary.countCommissions[0].employeeNumber}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned

Comment: I edited it again, with my reasoning, for this not to be marked as a duplicate. Or maybe it is, and I am just doing something wrong. BalusC never said what question this was a duplicate of, so I am assuming it is the link posted by STG, which does not work for me.

Comment: Uh, duplicate link is just in top of your question. Next time just directly ask for clarification instead of accusing.

Comment: @BalusC my apologies, I did not mean it to sound that way, really :) I really did miss the link to the question at the top of the page. First time here so I thought it would be somewhere at the bottom. Sorry :(

Comment: So, I went back a third time and got it to work. I am not sure what I had initially done wrong, but looking at the amount I had done thus far, Went back to bare minimum pojos, bypassed the wizard.  Now I can see the information.  Will start adding on more from there.